# Codeigniter 404 on live server

Tags: codeigniter

i'm running CI 3.0 with HMVC. On my local XAMPP everything works fine but on my (linux) live server i got an error 404 (Page Not Found) from CI.

I've hours and do everthing i found to solve this..without success!

Here is what i have right now:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'default';
```

**htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**My structure:**

-application

--modules

---default

----controllers

-----Default.php

**My Controller Default.php:**

```
class Default extends MY_Controller  {

 public function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();
 }

 public function index()
 {
     ....
 }
}
```

**Error in CI error log:**

ERROR - 2015-04-02 13:15:56 --> 404 Page Not Found: ../modules/default/controllers//index

..and still 404. What is wrong with this???

Comment: Make Sure your `Controller` file name Starts with Capital Letter. `Index.php`

Comment: Controller need to be named Default.php not index.php If I am getting right. Also one slash sufficient in path, so check how it is called. Also Index (index) is reserved name in CodeIgniter so you want to consider changing it to something else.

Comment: @Tpojka, [`"index"` is only reserved against being used as a **Controller** name](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html), however, there is nothing wrong with using `"index"` as a **function** name.  [Even the News Controller in the official tutorial in the documentation contains a function named `"index"`](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html).

Comment: Agree all of that. Also, I meant to Index.php controller. And finally, if you check his files and folders structure my previous comment will be more clarified. Also my comment goes to @Kamran Adil.

Answer (score 0):

Check all controllers and libraries are start capitalized **i.e Welcome**. In your core/MY_Controller have your extend it by **MX_Controller**

**core/MY_Controller**

`class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {}`

**config/routes.php**

`$route['default_controller'] = "default/default/index";`

Routes in hmvc need **module-name/controller-name/function**

And also when you download the hmvc from there download make sure you go to the branches and download the correct version for your codeigniter "HMVC Default Download" is for codeigniter 2

Though I think now only codeigniter hmvc 3 is available for download. https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

I use also htaccess in my main directory below. You also can download more htaccess files from here. http://www.insiderclub.org/ in the downloads section.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

For testing/developing with HMVC i renamed the original folders application/controllers to application/controllers_off.
 My controllers are located in:

application/modules/default/controllers/

So i think i can rename or delete the original folder

The folder application/controllers was empty but it seems that the HMVC extensions needed this folder. So renaming it back to "controllers" solved my problem.

Unbelievable!!!

Comment: Never ever delete something if you 'just think you could' untill you are not 100% clear with consequences. This can be remembered for anything related after turning on your machine.